# array of objects in C

Tags: c, object, struct, malloc

Hi I would like to know how to create an array of objects in C.
Here's my code. This obviously only prints out information of one object. I would like to create an array of students, then print out all their info. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int no;

typedef struct Student{
char name[30];
int age;
double gpa;
}Student;

void inputStudents(Student *s){
Student *p;
printf("Enter how many students you want : ");
scanf("%d", &no); 
p = (Student *)malloc(no * sizeof(Student));
if(p == NULL){
    exit(1);
}

for(int i = 0; i<no; i++){
    printf("What is student %d name?\n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &s->name);
    printf("What is student %d age?\n", i+1);
    scanf(" %d", &s->age);
    printf("What is student %d gpa?\n", i+1);
    scanf(" %lf", &s->gpa);
}


}

void printStudents(Student s){
  for(int i = 0; i<no; i++){
  printf("\n%d.)Name: %s\n", i+1, s.name);
  printf("Age: %d\n", s.age);
  printf("GPA: %.2lf\n", s.gpa);
 }
}

int main(){
    Student s;
    inputStudents(&s);
    printStudents(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]", &s->name);`  => `scanf(" %[^\n]", s->name);`. And you never store your values in the array you allocated.

Comment: `Student s;
    inputStudents(&s);` : `s` is one object. Also `p = (Student *)malloc(no * sizeof(Student));` : `p` unused for inputs and anythings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass in a pointer that will have a newly allocated array on it afterwards. This isn't the easiest way, but for educational purposes, here's what you need to change to do it right...

Your array of students is represented by a pointer. Thus, to mutate it, you must pass in a pointer to a pointer.

```
void inputStudents(Student *s){
// should be changed to:
void inputStudents(Student **s){
```

Now you can use `p` the way you were doing it if you make this change:

```
p = (Student *)malloc(no * sizeof(Student));
*s = p; // s now points to a pointer to an array of Students
```

Why? You cannot reassign `s` if you want to mutate the input, so instead, you'll assign a pointed-to pointer (`*s`) to `p`.

Change main so it passes a pointer to a pointer, and also free the memory dynamically allocated by `inputStudents`:

```
int main(){
    Student *s; // we use a pointer now
    inputStudents(&s); // pass in a pointer to the pointer
    printStudents(s);
    free(s); // because s now points to malloc'd data we no longer need!

    return 0;
}
```

And similarly with your print function:

```
void printStudents(Student *s){ // now takes an array of students
  for(int i = 0; i<no; i++){
  printf("\n%d.)Name: %s\n", i+1, s[i].name); // use the ith Student in s
  printf("Age: %d\n", s[i].age);
  printf("GPA: %.2lf\n", s[i].gpa);
 }
}
```

Lastly, in your `inputStudents` iteration, you need to be writing to different parts of `p`:

```
for(int i = 0; i<no; i++){
    printf("What is student %d name?\n", i+1);
    scanf(" %[^\n]", &p[i].name); // mutate the ith student in p
    // ...
}
```